# Integration with ZOHO invoice

Tags: php, curl, invoice, zoho

I am exploring Zoho-invoice api and trying to integrate with my application. But i am stuck and cant find out what is the reason.

Please help :

This is how i am calling the API :

```
$fields = array(
                    'contact_name' => urlencode([name]),
                    'billing_address' => array('address' => urlencode([address]), 'city' => urlencode([city]), 'state' => urlencode([state]), 'zip' => urlencode([pincode]), 'country' => urlencode([country])),
                    'contact_person_id' => urlencode([id]),
                    'email' => urlencode([email])
            );
$jsonData = json_encode($fields);

//Initialize connection 
$ch = curl_init("https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/contacts?authtoken=[authtoken]&organization_id=[id]&JSONString={$jsonData}"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);//standard i/o streams 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);// Turn off the server and peer verification 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);//Set to return data to string ($response) 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);//Regular post   

//Execute cUrl session 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am sending correct auth-token and organization key.

But I am getting this error response :

```
 "code":1048,"message":"Sorry, there was an internal error. Please contact support@zohoinvoice.com for assistance."
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Use $info = curl_getinfo($ch); and then echo '<pre>';print_r($info);echo '</pre>'; and see the status and errors!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see you posting your json data in your code. Add these with your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json") );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$jsonData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sample PHP Class which creates Invoice in Zoho Invoice using Zoho Invoice API v3. [You can find it on GitHub](https://github.com/RokMeglic/zoho_invoice_v3_php).

```
/**
* Sends the actual request to the REST webservice
*/
protected function sendRequest($url, $data, $type = 'POST') {
 $jsonData = json_encode($this->urlencode_array($data));

 if ($type == 'POST') {
    $ch = curl_init("https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/{$url}?authtoken={$this->data['authtoken']}&organization_id={$this->data['organization_id']}&JSONString={$jsonData}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);//standard i/o streams
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);// Turn off the server and peer verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);//Set to return data to string ($response)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);//Regular post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json") );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
 } else {
    $ch = curl_init("https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/{$url}?authtoken={$this->data['authtoken']}&organization_id={$this->data['organization_id']}&JSONString={$jsonData}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);//standard i/o streams
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);// Turn off the server and peer verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);//Set to return data to string ($response)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);//Regular post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json") );
}


$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);

// RM: IS not object, is not code 0?
if (is_object($result) === false || $result->code != 0) {
   throw new AppException('Error creating estimate/invoice - '.print_r($result, true));
}

return $result;
```

}